# How to retain pixel dimensions when exporting to PNG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, export, png

In Adobe Illustrator, I'm creating for a screen size of 800px X 480px but while exporting to png/jpeg my file size gets changed to 3333px X 2000px. I don't know what's happening? Whatever the file size I create, it exports to these dimensions (3333px x 2000px).

Is there any solution?

Comment: 800x480px @ 72ppi == 3333x2000px @ 300ppi

Answer (score 3):

You should specify a resolution of 72 dpi in the save dialog or then use the save for web option.